# How do i split up an array that holds an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

Hello my fellow JS friends,

I am letting a user import a csv file (excel sheet) and i convert that into 
an array. which has 472 rows and 87 columns in this case.

so my array looks like this:
[image]

and everything is separated by commas like a usual array.

The issue is I need to separate the array within the array and when i do that i get an array with the length of 9 million, which i think is wrong

```
        vm.allTextLines = files.split(/\r\n|\n/);

        var headers = vm.allTextLines[0].split(',');

        vm.columnCount = headers.length;
        vm.rowCount = vm.allTextLines.length - 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < vm.allTextLines.length; i++) {
            // split content based on comma
            var data = vm.allTextLines[i].split(',');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {
                var tarr = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    tarr.push(data[j]);
                }
                vm.lines.push(tarr);
            }
        }

            //this is where i split the array that contains the csv
            //data and put it into its own array I believe this is 
            //where the issue is.
            for(var i=1;i<vm.allTextLines.length; i++){

            vm.uniqueAll.push(vm.allTextLines[i].split(','));

            for(var j=0; j < vm.uniqueAll.length; j++){

                for(var r =0; r < vm.uniqueAll[j].length; r++){

                    vm.arrayOfValuesOfFile.push(vm.uniqueAll[j][r]);
                }
            }

        }
```

If you can help me correct this for each I would appreciate it alot.

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you about the place of error, because it seems you nested the loop in a wrong way. Following a snippet where you can check what I mean. 
i.e:

```js
let vm = {
  allTextLines:['h1,h2,h3','row1val1,row1val2,row1val3', 'row2val1,row2val2,row2val3'],
  uniqueAll: [],
  arrayOfValuesOfFile:[]
}
// Here you should not nest the loop 
for(var i=1;i<vm.allTextLines.length; i++){
  vm.uniqueAll.push(vm.allTextLines[i].split(','));
}
for(var j=0; j < vm.uniqueAll.length; j++){
  for(var r =0; r < vm.uniqueAll[j].length; r++){
    vm.arrayOfValuesOfFile.push(vm.uniqueAll[j][r]);
  }
}

console.log('allTextLines', vm.allTextLines);
console.log('uniqueAll', vm.uniqueAll);
console.log('arrayOfValuesOfFile', vm.arrayOfValuesOfFile);
```

Of Course you could easily optimize the algorithm:

```js
let vm = {
  allTextLines:['h1,h2,h3','row1val1,row1val2,row1val3', 'row2val1,row2val2,row2val3'],
  uniqueAll: [],
  arrayOfValuesOfFile:[]
}

for(var i=1;i<vm.allTextLines.length; i++){
  let currentLinesValue = vm.allTextLines[i].split(',');
  vm.uniqueAll.push(currentLinesValue);
    for(var r =0; r < currentLinesValue.length; r++){
      vm.arrayOfValuesOfFile.push(currentLinesValue[r]);
    
  }
}
console.log('allTextLines', vm.allTextLines);
console.log('uniqueAll', vm.uniqueAll);
console.log('arrayOfValuesOfFile', vm.arrayOfValuesOfFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should transform you bidimensional array into a one-dimension array.

```
var allTogether = []; // Array with all your CSV (no matter from which file it came from)
for (var i = 0; vm.allTextLines.length; i++) {
    allTogether.push(vm.allTextLines[i]); // Gets the CSV line an adds to a one-dimension array
}

// Now you can iterate over the one-dimension array
for (var i = 0; allTogether.length; i++) {
    var csvFields = allTogether[i].split(',');
    // Here goes your code that works with the CSV fields.
}
```